# Spring/JPA/Hibernate persist entity : Nothing happen

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to make an application with Spring 3, JPA 2 and Hibernate 3.
I have a problem when y persist an entity : nothing happen ! Data are not inserted in database, and not query is executed.
But when i'm using a request like query.getResultList() a select works correctly.

So I think my problem is only on a persist/update and on the transaction manager but i'm not really good with spring.
Can you help me please ?

Here are my configuration files :

> ### My applicationContext.xml

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="soireeentreamis_DS" jndi-name="jdbc/soireeentreamis" />

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="soireeentreamis_DS" />
        <property name="dataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="soireeentreamisDS" value-ref="soireeentreamis_DS" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="soireeentreamisPU" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soireeentreamisTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="soireeentreamisTransactionManager" />

    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

> ### My persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="soireeentreamisPU"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>soireeentreamisDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

> ### My service
>
> ```
> @Service
> @Transactional("soireeentreamisTransactionManager")
> public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService ...
> ```
>
> ### My dao
>
> ```
> @Repository
> public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User, String> implements
>         UserDao {  
> @PersistenceContext(unitName = "soireeentreamisPU")
> private EntityManager em;   
> public void persist(final User entity) {
>         em.persist(entity);
>     }
> }
> ```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: it looks like transaction problem to me, maybe try add @Transactional also on methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to add the @transactional to my createUser method in UserServiceImpl, but i have the same problem :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find similar problem a while ago. In my case I needed to add line below to my dispacher-servlet.xml. So I need this in 2 places (applicationContex.xml and dispacher-servlet.xml)

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

And to clear something out, you didn't show your service methode that "store" object, but I believe that it's annotated with @Transactional - cause wihout this one you want create new transaction.

Comment: Yes ! It's the solution ! I don't understand why it works, but it's ok for me. thanks for your help !

Comment: Look at the answer of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483006/entities-not-persisting-spring-hibernate-jpa it will help to understand why this works

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me recently. The problem is as you say a transactional problem, add the @Transactional annotation to all the methods that update the DB. Then add the [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) library to your calsspath or add it to your pom.xml if you are using Maven, this is necessary for spring make transactions. Even if I did it on a different way I hope it can help you. Here is my db.xml where I have all the data base related spring configuration.

```
<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="1" />
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="4" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="3" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100" />
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

And here is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="pu-app" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution but i have the same problem :( I had cglib 2.2.2 in my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the model object into the persistence.xml file.  Right below the provider element add

```
<class>com.your.domain.object.User</class>
```

Comment: I did it, but I've the same problem. I don't know if it can help but, when y persist it calls SharedEntityManagerCreator.SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(...), this methold "EntityManager target =
     EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(this.targetFactory, this.properties)" return null...