# Spring/JPA/Vaadin on Tomcat - Not persisting entity

Tags: spring, tomcat, jpa, vaadin

I have a webapp that uses the stack Spring, JPA(Hibernate impl) and Vaadin 7 on a Tomcat 7 server. The problem is that the entity manager is not persisting entity's. Also, no error/exception is thrown. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483006/entities-not-persisting-spring-hibernate-jpa) can hold the answer, but I'm not sure.

To use Vaadin 7 with Spring I use the [Spring Vaadin addon](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/springvaadinintegration).

Because the number of files, here is an overview:

- src / main / webapp / META-INF / context.xml
- src / main / webapp / WEB-INF / web.xml
- src / main / webapp / WEB-INF / application-context.xml
- src / main / java / com / ks / places / MyUI.java (autowires placeService and creates Place entity)
- src / main / java / com / ks / places / model / Place.java (the entity in question)
- src / main / java / com / ks / places / dao /  PlaceDao.java
- src / main / java / com / ks / places / dao /  PlaceDaoImpl.java
- src / main / java / com / ks / places / service /  PlaceService.java
- src / main / java / com / ks / places / service /  PlaceServiceImpl.java

This is my code:

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<!-- Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Vaadin servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.xpoft.vaadin.SpringVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Vaadin UI to display</description>
        <param-name>beanName</param-name>
        <param-value>myUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>systemMessagesBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Vaadin Production/debug mode -->
<context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JNDI datasource -->
<resource-ref>
    <description>JNDI Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/placesPU</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

WEB-INF/application-config.xml (Spring config)

```
<!-- component scan for @Component, @Repositry, @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ks.places" />

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for eg @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/placesPU" resource-ref="true" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="placesPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ks.places.model" />

    <!-- this is important to connect JPA and JdbcTemplate transaction control -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="hibernateJpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id='transactionManager' class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager'>
    <property name='entityManagerFactory' ref='entityManagerFactory' />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="hibernateJpaDialect" />
</bean>

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- Spring's exception translation -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Spring container will act as a JPA container and inject an EnitityManager from your EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean class="ru.xpoft.vaadin.VaadinMessageSource" />
```

META-INF/context.xml (Tomcat context file)

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Places">

<Resource   name="jdbc/placesPU" 
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.36:3306/places"
            username="root"
            password="pass" 
            removeAbandoned="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="90"
            logAbandoned="true" 
            maxActive="20" 
            maxIdle="10" 
            maxWait="-1" />

</Context>
```

PlaceDao.java

```
public interface PlaceDao {

    public void save(Place place);

}
```

PlaceDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository("placeDao")
public class PlaceDaoImpl implements PlaceDao {

    // @PersistenceContext(unitName="placesPU") // also tried this
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="placesPU")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Place place) {
        entityManager.persist(place);
        entityManager.flush(); <- gives an TransactionRequiredException exception
    }

}
```

PlaceService.java

```
public interface PlaceService {

    void save(Place place);

}
```

PlaceServiceImpl.java

```
//@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false) // also tried this
@Service("placeService")    
public class PlaceServiceImpl implements PlaceService {

    @Autowired
    private PlaceDao placeDao;

    //@Transactional // also tried this
    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    @Override
    public void save(Place place) {
        placeDao.save(place);
    }

}
```

MyUI.java

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyUI extends UI implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private PlaceService placeService;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

                Place place = new Place();
                place.setName("vandaag");

                placeService.save(place);

                // No entity was added to the database...

            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(button);
    }

}
```

**The transaction**

When I persist the Place entity (placeService.save() in MyUI.java) I do not get any error or exception. But, when I manually try to flush the entityManager I do get an error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:983)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
at $Proxy16.flush(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
at $Proxy16.flush(Unknown Source)
at com.ks.places.dao.PlaceDaoImpl.save(PlaceDaoImpl.java:44)
```

Comment: could you copy/paste your logs to check if your transaction is correct ?

Comment: Thx. I updated the question with the exception I get. Or did you mean other logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception clearly says, that your `@Transactional` annotation is not taken into account at all.

I suggest you remove the `mode="aspectj"` from `<tx:annotation-driven ... />`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

The default `mode` is `proxy`. For `aspectj` you need full AspectJ-support (and I currently don't see a reason why you should need that). AspectJ weaving requires spring-aspects.jar on the classpath, as well as load-time weaving (or compile-time weaving) enabled.

(And by the way you don't need `proxy-target-class="true"` as you have interfaces for you services.)

Comment: You are right... I can't believe I didn't try that. Must of been because I was struggling for 2 days with it and didn't saw clearly.